# Writing to a PDF with fields from SQL Server 2005

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server-2005, pdf

I'm running an asp.net 4 / c# site using SQL Server 2005 and want to write column values from within SQL Server into a PDF file which already has content inside it (I want to personalise a PDF voucher that you get from the logged in page on my site)

Is there an easy tutorial to look at or is this a much bigger job?

Comment: What's the problem? Getting the data out of SQL Server or writing to a PDF? I'm just asking because it doesn't seem like a single question should have to address both issues. Getting things out of SQL Server is easy enough (and well documented all over the internet, including SO). Are you having trouble with the PDF part?

Comment: Sorry yes, i know about sql what i want to do is pull a customers address and put it into a PDF that they download

Answer (score 1):

There are two parts here:

1. Read data from database (for example, using ADO.NET, Entity Framework, e.t.c.)
2. Write that data to a PDF document (using some free or commercial PDF tool, like iTextSharp, SharpPDF, XPDF, Docotic.Pdf, e.t.c)

You can look at [this article](http://bitmiracle.com/blog/write-data-from-a-database-to-pdf) that describes both parts in detail.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I think you have several options out there.

For example, you can [create a PDF document based on a template using iTextSharp](http://www.johnnycode.com/blog/2010/03/05/using-a-template-to-programmatically-create-pdfs-with-c-and-itextsharp/).
In that case, the template is the existing voucher you mention. You'd have to replace the information inside it, by identifying the fields, or something like that.
Something similar could also be accomplished using [PDFSharp](http://pdfsharp.com/).

Just pay special attention when using iTextSharp to its license agreement, since its AGPL, which means your software must be GPL/AGPL as well.

Now, if you want to avoid interacting with PDF objects, and APIs, you have one other alternative. Which is to create an RDLC local report, and [directly export it to PDF from your codebehind](http://forums.asp.net/t/1556522.aspx/2/10). In this case, it wouldn't be based on an existing voucher, it would be created from scratch.